# Firefox proxy settings changed after Kaspersky uninstall

Tags: firefox, iframe

After uninstalling the virus scanner my settings were changed, like the proxy settings.
PROBLEM:
If I log into an application that is presented in an iFrame, the application page will open up but no longer in the iFrame but take over the entire browser.

It worked before, it still works on my colleagues PCs with the same FF version 3.6.12, it works on my IE but can't figure out the setting in my Firefox to get it to work.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with programming. It would be more appropriate to ask this on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar with Firefox in the past where site layout became corrupted. I found that by going into "Tools" > "Clear Recent History" and ensuring that "Site Preferences" was checked, caused the sites to render correctly after Firefox was restarted.